# Is it possible to have the datasource of a asp.net repeater be a list<string> that is a property of a class?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datasource

Here is the aspx for my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Files" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_FileNameHeader" Text="File Name" /></th>                       
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>            
           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_FileName" Text='<%# Eval("JobFileNames")  %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>       
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code for binding the data in C#:

```
rpt_Files.DataSource = CurrentQuote;
    rpt_Files.DataBind();
```

And here is the class definition of CurrentQuote:

```
public class CurrentQuote
{
// Properties
private List<string> _jobfilenames;
public List<string> JobFileNames
{
    get
    {
        if (_jobfilenames != null)
            return _jobfilenames;
        else
        {
            _jobfilenames = new List<string>();
            return _jobfilenames;
        }
    }

    set { _jobfilenames = value; }
}
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
An invalid data source is being used for rpt_Files. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.
```

If I change the repeaters datasource to CurrentQuote.JobFileNames I receive an error stating that string has no property called "JobFileNames".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have one quote with multiple files your DataSource should look something like this:

```
CurrentQuote cq = new CurrentQuote();
string[] filenames = new string[] { "file1", "file2", "file3" };
cq.JobFileNames = filenames.ToList();

rpt_Files.DataSource = cq.JobFileNames;
rpt_Files.DataBind();
```

Then in the markup you can use:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_FileName" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
```

So yes "It is possible to have the datasource of a asp.net repeater be a list that is a property of a class" but you should instantiate the class first and from markup you have to access directly the DataItem since it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign DataSource to a List of objects like this:

```
List<CurrentQuote> myCurrentQuoteList = new List<CurrentQuote>();
CurrentQuote  currentQuoteObj = new CurrentQuote();  
currentQuoteObj.JobFileNames.Add("test");
myCurrentQuoteList.Add(myCurrentQuoteList );  

rpt_Files.DataSource = myCurrentQuoteList;
rpt_Files.DataBind();
```

You cannot directly assign a class Object, you should implement IListSource or IEnumerable to be used as your data source.

Comment: It stinks that there is not a .SingleItemDataSource